# Fear of CSS will be overridden by other css files

Tags: html, css, sass

Description:

I just copy and pasted login page from other module and redesigned it.
Let's say structure is like below now:

```
HTML
  login.html
  login_redesign.html
CSS
  login.css
  login_redesign.css
```

I am including both css file in some global file in sequence of login.css first and login_redesign.css second.

Senario:
I am working on login_redesign.css
Now, to avoid my changes overriding login.css component (as I am loading login_redesign.css at last), I added

> class = "new_login_page"

at top level element of login_redesign.html

login_redesign.html:

```
<div class = "main new_login_page">
  <div>....
</div>
```

login.html:

```
<div class = "main">... </div>
```

Also, added that class in my login_redesign.css file as:

```
.new_login_page.main {
  .header {
    width:320px;
  }
}
```

While, original page has as below:

```
.main {
  .header {
    width:1020px;
  }
}
```

My concern is as follow:

> What if in future if someone add back-ground color property in original css file i.e. login.css as below:

```
.main {
  .header {
    width:320px;
  }
  .body {
    .background-color:orange // this line was there for both the codes
    .leftHalf {
      background-color:white; // new line added
    }
  }
}
```

It will give white color to my file's (login_redesign.html's) leftHalf part as well, because there is no `background-color` property defined inside .leftHalf in lgoin_redesign.css file.

How can I prevent this changes to my file?

> One more level of complexity: both login.html and login_redesign.html are using css from `root` level file 'common.css' which is loaded even before login.css

With this added dependency, I want to block changes from login.html but not from common.css

Thank you for reading though the whole question and the answer may be really simple for this question as I am really just reading through stackoverflow to get my task done on css, which I have not worked with much.

Comment: this is not valid CSS (i.e. the nested selectors). So you are either using a preprocessor or framework, which you should mention in the question, or your CSS won't work as desired due to the nesting.

Comment: @Johannes I am using sass. Just gigin a gist of what is a problem.

Comment: I suggest prefixing your classes to avoid unwanted inheritance. You'll also find trouble with generic selectors influencing your classes. Such are the woes of dealing with multiple sources of css without full control.